# Automated backup removal on Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

We are using the process described in the [App Engine Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#scheduled_backups) to perform a daily automated backup of all our datastore tables. Since the number of backups is starting to grow out of bounds (cost, but also breaks the admin page apparently), I would like to clean up my backups in an automated way, but I can't seem to find how to do this.

I tried to use the timestamps on GCS (where the backups are stored) to delete the actual data. I was hoping this would also remove the backup from the table on the datastore admin page, but it doesn't: i need to manually delete the backups there too (which is made extra annoying by not being able to see all the backups, only the last X).

What is the recommended way to automatically keep a limited set of backups of the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question elsewhere (forgot where exactly, I think the appengine forum). The backup system stores its information in *AE** datastore tables of your app, so a workaround is to delete these entries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use object versioning in combination with lifecycle management on Google Cloud storage.

- [Object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) makes it possible to continuously overwrite your objects, since you can go back to the older versions.
- [Lifecycle management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) allows you to setup rules like : "Keep only the 3 most recent versions of each object in a bucket with versioning enabled"

Comment: My problem isn't with GCS object management, but with the cloud datastore DB backup mechanism (which happens to use GCS as the backing storage). I don't control what properties the DB backup mechanism sets on the GCS objects, but even that's not important: my point was that even if i make the GCS objects disappear, the backups in the internal backup database stay.